# Unable to get all messages from a channel in Telegram with MadelineProto

Tags: php, telegram

I wanted to get all messages from a telegram channel using MadelineProto. I followed the steps according to their documentation:  https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/messages.getHistory.html

Here is my code

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$channel = '-1001433544229';
$offset_id = 0;
$limit = 100;

$messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory(
    ['peer' => $channel,
    'offset_id' => 0,
    'offset_date' => 0, 
    'add_offset' => 0, 
    'limit' => $limit, 
    'max_id' => 9999999999, 
    'min_id' => 0, 
    'hash' => 0]);
echo json_encode($messages_Messages);
```

The problem is that it returns an empty object. What is the issue? Could there be an update that we cant retrieve messsages from channels in Telegram anymore? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if you can get an error code. Maybe a missing auth-token? I wonder what the string `'session.madeline'` is for, is there any documentation on that?

Comment: @dreua Other methods work, so its not an auth-token issue. The 'session.madeline' is there to save my session with telegram.

Answer (score 0):

After asking some people in the madeline proto community, it turned out the solution was just to add

```
$MadelineProto->async(false)
```

after the $MadelineProto->start(); method.